# Calculate number of function calls in the same function

Tags: php

How to calculate(determine) in php the total number of a function calls but the result of this must be in the same function for which I calculate this number.

Exemple:
The test() function is called 100 times(this number is variable and so I don't know it from beginning). I want to find this number in the block of function

```
test();

function test(){



$no_calls =....
echo $no_calls;  

}
```

I want the message from echo to be shown only once not to every call of function.

Comment: This is a good example where globals are useful.

Comment: don't pollute your global scope! don't expose your function-specific variable to tampering by any other code!

Comment: I use this for example `function debug_log( $object=null, $label=null ) { static $debug_log_iteration = 0; $debug_log_iteration += 1; $message = json_encode($object, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); $label = "log_iteration: $debug_log_iteration\\nlog_label:     " . ($label ? $label : '< not given >') . "\\nlog_message:  "; echo "<script>console.log('$label', $message);</script>"; }`

Answer (score 12):

use a [static](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) variable, like this

```
function test(){
  static $no_calls = 0;
  ...
  ++$no_calls;
}
```

$no_calls will keep its value between calls

In response to your edit, you could do something like this:

```
function test() {
  static $no_calls = 0;
  ++$no_calls;
  ...
  return $no_calls;
}

test();
test();
test();
$final = test();
echo $final;  // will be 4
```

ok, let's try this a third time:

```
function test($last_time = false) {
  static $no_calls = 0;
  ++$no_calls;
  ...
  if($last_time)
  {
    echo $no_calls;
  }
}

test();
test();
test();
test(true);  // will echo 4
```

OK, let's try this one more time:

```
class Test {
  private $no_calls;
  function test()
  {
    ...
    ++$this->no_calls;
  }
  function __destruct()
  {
    echo $this->no_calls;
  }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->test();
$test->test();
$test->test();
$test->test();
//when $test falls out of scope, 4 will be echoed.
```

so, we need to magically echo the number of times a function is called: only once, inside the function, without using classes, *and* without telling the function that it is the last call.  Hold on to your hats (warning, I do not suggest using this code for many reasons (but you leave me no choice), and it WILL NOT work if there is to be any output in between function calls, including by the function itself):

```
function test() {
  static $no_calls = 1;
  if($no_calls == 1)
  {
    ob_start();
  }
  else
  {
    ++$no_calls;
    ob_clean();
  }
  echo $no_calls;
}
```

In this instance, when the script terminates, the output buffering left open will automatically flush to the browser.

Comment: I want the echo statement to be in the function

Comment: $last_time must be set to TRUE in the function not outside.

Comment: you want the function to know, _all by itself_, when it is the last time it is called?

Comment: @BoiculeseIuli The closest you're going to come is by doing it in a destructor.  See my edit.

Comment: exactly, I want the function to know, all by itself, when it is the last time it is called but if possible to not use classes

Comment: thanks anyway for you try to help me. I know it's strange what I want but I've no choice to change this workflow of code

Answer (score 3):

```
    <?php
        test();
        test();
        test();
        test();

        $NoOfCalls=0;
        function test(){
         global $NoOfCalls;
         echo ++$NoOfCalls;

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function test() {
   static $calls = 0;
   $calls++;
   echo "this function has been called $calls times";
}

test(); // 1 times
test(); // 2 times
test(); // 3 times
```

If you need that `calls` value to be available outside of the function, you'll either have to return it from the function (`return $calls`, or assign it to a global variable somewhere.

Comment: For your code it will show 3 times that message from echo, but I want to show it once not to every call

Comment: You'd have to pass something into the function, then, to tell it to display the message or not.

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

```
function test() {
   static $count = 0;
   $count++;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make global variable and increment it in function. And when you check total call count, you can use that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Sloppy code, but it should be understandable enough. It utilizes the [`__destruct`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) of the object to only print the summary once. Also it uses [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) to automagically detect what function is calling it. This will work if you call multiple functions too (like `test`, `test2`, `some_random_function`).

```
<?php

class Counter {

    private $_count = array();

    public function count_call()
    {
        list(, $prev) = debug_backtrace();
        $this->_count[$prev['function']] = isset($this->_count[$prev['function']])
            ? $this->_count[$prev['function']] + 1
            : 1;
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        echo '<h2>Calls per function:</h2>';
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($this->_count);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}


$counter = new Counter();

function test() {
    global $counter;
    $counter->count_call();
    echo 'called test<br />';
}

$rand = rand(5, 10);
echo "calls to be made: {$rand}<br />";
for ($i = 0; $i < $rand; $i++) {
    test();
}
```

Comment: And of course you can get rid of that global in various ways, like simply passing it along to `test()` as an argument, dependency injection, registry, etc..

Answer (score 0):

While i was looking for new functions to handle some function call counts. i know that the xhprof extensions can collect thouse things and much more which can be very interessting. **without implementing debug code**